# Vertical Form Fields Acting Weird

Tags: html, css, wordpress, forms, shortcode

I created a vertical form with Contact Form 7 with the following code:

```css
input[type="phone"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
    color: black;
  }
  
  input[type="phone"]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
input[type="text"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
  color: black;
}
input[type="text"]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0;
}

.wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-submit {
  width: 40% !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  background-color: #ff6600 !important;
  color: #0E1428 !important;
  font-family: open sans hebrew condensed;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-weight: 900;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 100em;
  display: inline-block;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 250px;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0%,
  20%,
  60%,
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-20px);
    transform: translateY(-20px);
  }
  80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px);
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
}

input[type="submit"]:hover {
  width: 40% !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  background-color: #0E1428 !important;
  color: #ff6600 !important;
  font-family: open sans hebrew condensed;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: normal !important;
  font-weight: 900;
  animation: bounce 1s;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 100em;
  display: inline-block;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-width: 250px;
}

body .cf7-style input[type=”text”]:focus,
body .cf7-style input[type=”email”]:focus,
body .cf7-style textarea:focus {
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.5s ease !important;
  opacity: 0 !important;
}

[placeholder]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
}

[placeholder] {
  width: 25% !important;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8) !important;
  height: 40px !important;
  color: black !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center !important;
  border-radius: 10px !important;
  display: inline-block;
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
  font-family: open sans hebrew condensed !important;
  font-style: italic;
  border: 2px solid #0E1428 !important;
  min-width: 164px;
}

[placeholder]:focus {
  background-color: rgba(221, 221, 221, 0.8) !important;
  transition: opacity 0.5s 0.5s ease !important;
  font-family: open sans hebrew condensed !important;
  font-style: italic !important;
  border: 2px solid #ff6600 !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #719ECE !important;
  min-width: 164px;
}
```

```html
<center>

  <label for=".elementor-6 .elementor-element.elementor-element-5m0lukt .wpcf7 input[type=" text "]"><input type=text textarea name="your-name" placeholder="שם" required id:name </input></label> <label for=".wpcf7-form-control.wpcf7-text.wpcf7-tel.wpcf7-validates-as-required.wpcf7-validates-as-tel* your-email"> <input type="phone" textarea name="your-phone" input placeholder="טלפון" id:phone required</input></label>  [submit "!אני רוצה עוד פרטים"]
</center>
```

Comment: Not able to replicate the issue. which browser are you seeing this behavior on ?

Comment: Hey, thanks for wanting to help. Chrome, here's a temporary link:  http://berko.createak.co.il/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inspected the link given, it seems like both your **inputs are using different styling**.

Firstly in your HTML, the left input has `type="text"` and the right has `type="phone"`. Not sure if this right.

If that is correct then you could tweek your CSS. There seems to be few styles that are NOT applied to input with `type="phone"` and due to this difference in styles, the right one looks different.

```
form input[type="text"], form input[type="password"], form input[type="email"], form input[type="url"], form input[type="date"], form input[type="month"], form input[type="time"], form input[type="datetime"], form input[type="datetime-local"], form input[type="week"], form input[type="number"], form input[type="search"], form input[type="tel"], form input[type="color"], form select, form textarea {
 ....
}
```

In the above CSS if you add `form input[type="phone"]`, the second should behave correctly as well.

**OR**

in HTML change the second input to `type="tel"` to fix (No CSS change in this case)

```
<input type="tel" textarea name="your-phone" input placeholder="טלפון" id:phone required</input>
```

Comment: So the left one is "name" and the right one is "phone", therefore the left one has the input: type="text". The right one has the input: type="phone".

Comment: The left one is `type="text"` and few styles are being applied to only to text and NOT `type="phone"`. Just add `form input[type="phone"]` to the above shown CSS

Comment: I have edited the answer, you could also change the second input to `type="tel"` to fix without any CSS change